# Can we use Haskell for Web Development with the Razor engine?

Tags: haskell, azure

I am very new to Haskell but as it is a functional programming language(easy to use functions) i have got some interest in working with it.Currently i am developing an app for Windows azure i was thinking is there a way to integrate Haskell with Razor engine so i can use it.Is there any resource(Internet link) for using Haskell with Razor.Can we use Haskell in with .net language(as i am developing using Webmatrix3)?

For eg

RAZOR CODE WITH COMMENTS

```
@*
A logic that calls haskell
Uses a link to acess a haskell file(*.hs)
goes to prelude
Prelude>
pi*r^2
uses a function can we apply Haskell this way in Razor

*@
```

Comment: Instead of Haskell you could also look at F# as it is both in .NET already and a functional language. Obviously you would not get the nice Haskell syntax but that is a matter of taste. Otherwise you could make a DLL and include it in your project, ymmv though.

Comment: Thanks for the info Alessandro but somehow i am trying with Haskell love for that Language is growing day by day.Yes, i will have a look in F#

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One approach would be to use something like hint to invoke ghc as a service: http://hackage.haskell.org/package/hint

You could also use mueval, if you remove the posix-dependencies within it: http://hackage.haskell.org/package/mueval